# Getting Facebook Image using graph api - bigger image than picture.type(large)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im requesting the users image like so:

```
FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields":@"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender, birthday, age_range"} HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
```

But the large image is still quite small, is there a way to request a larger image, or even better, and `xlarge` image. It was a shot in the dark but i tried `picture.type(xlarge)` but it caused an error.

Comment: This is the largest size you can specify when retrieving the picture field.

The picture type must be one of the following values: small, normal, album, large, square

One option would be to get the album for "profile pictures" and look for the particular photo you want.
e.g. [album_id]/photos?fields=link,name,source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a width and height using something like picture.width(200) or picture.height(200) for the sizes that you want, and the graph api will return a url for the picture that's closest to that size. Note that not all profile pictures will have the size that you want, so you will still need to handle smaller images.

Comment: Can this be requested using the same method as above (Graph API) or is it a separate request? Link or coding example would be great.

Comment: Same as above, just replace picture.type(large) with picture.width(200)